# Prove or disprove if $L_{1}$ is undecidable and $L_{2}$ is finite language then $L_{1} \cup L_{2}$ is undecidable

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem

I tried to prove by contradiction.

$L_{1}$ is undecidable and $L_{2}$ is finite language then $\overline{L_{1}}\cap \overline{L_{2}}$ is decidable.
$$L_{1} = \overline{HALT_{TM}} = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ doesn't halt on input } w \big\}$$
$$L_{2}=\emptyset$$
then,
$$\overline L_{1}={HALT_{TM}}=\big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M\text{ is TM and }M\text{ halts on input }w \big\}$$
$$\overline L_{2}=\Sigma^{*}$$
The intersection, $\overline{L_{1}}\cap \overline{L_{2}}$ is $\overline L_{1}={HALT_{TM}}$ is decidable and this is the contradiction.

Is it true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your proof is not correct. The claim you want to prove or disprove is:

> The union of *any* undecidable language and *any* finite language is undecidable.

To do a proof by contradiction, you need to take the opposite:

> The union of *some* undecidable language and *some* finite language is decidable.

Note that the "any" (universal quantifier) turns into "some" (existential quantifier) when you apply the negation.

You showed that a contradiction follows from:

> The union of *any* undecidable language and *any* finite language is decidable.

But unfortunately, that only proves:

> The union of *some* undecidable language and *some* finite language is undecidable.

In other words, you can't just pick specific languages and show that their union is decidable: you need to show that your proof will work for *any* arbitrary $L_1$ and $L_2$ fitting the requirements.

I would suggest that you instead start with an arbitrary undecidable $L_1$ and finite $L_2$ and, from there, show that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is undecidable. Here's a hint to get you started: is $L_1 \setminus L_2$ decidable or not?

Comment: All right, I look at an arbitrary undecidable $L_{1}$ and finite $L_{2}$, $L_1 \setminus L_2$ isn't decidable because then I can use the language $L_{2}$ for any undecidable languages, just subtract $L_{2}$ from, to decide the language.
So, it's the same about the union of them?

Thanks.

Comment: if I take some undecidable language $L_{1} = A_{TM} = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ accepts } w \big\}$  and some finite language $L_{2} = \emptyset$, then their union is $L_{1}$ that is undecidable.

Comment: @Asaf Close, but you're mixing up "some" and "any" again. Your example shows that for *some* languages $L_1 \setminus L_2$ is undecidable, but you haven't proven that for *all*. (You're on the right track though!)

Comment: I used it by the contradiction that you wrote: `The union of some undecidable language and some finite language is decidable.`
If the contradiction is true, I can take some undecidable language $L_{1} = A_{TM} = \big\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is TM and }M \text{ accepts } w \big\}$
and and some finite language $L_{2} = \emptyset$, their union must be decidable. 
Their union is undecidable, and that is the contradiction.

Comment: @Asaf Ah, but you're going in the wrong direction. You need to *start* with "the union of some undecidable language and some finite language is decidable" and go forward from that to get a contradiction. Basically, assume you have some undecidable $L_1$ and some finite $L_2$ such that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is decidable, and go from there. You can't assume *anything else* about the two languages. You can't set them to specific values, in particular.

Comment: $L_{1} \cup L_{2}$ is decidable $\leftrightarrow\overline{L_{1}}\cap\overline{L_{2}}$ is decidable.
That leads to $L_{1} \cup L_{2}$ is recognizable.$\leftrightarrow\overline{L_{1}}\cap\overline{L_{2}}$ is recognizable.

$L_{2}$ is decidable $\leftrightarrow\overline{L_{2}}$ is decidable.
That leads to $L_{2}$ is recognizable $\leftrightarrow\overline{L_{2}}$ is recognizable.

$L_{1}$ is undecidable.
That leads to $L_{1}$ is unrecognizable XOR $\overline{L_{1}}$ is unrecognizable.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I start with $L_{1} \cup L_{2}$ is decidable.

Decidable languages are closed under difference.
So, $(L_{1} \cup L_{2}) \setminus  L_{2}$ must be decidable.

$(L_{1} \cup L_{2}) \setminus  L_{2}= L_{1}$ but $L_{1}$ is undecidable.

Comment: This is true only if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are non-overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction. Suppose that for all $L_1$ undecidable and $L_2$ finite $\overline{L_1} \cap \overline{L_2}$ is decidable. Pick $L_1$ any undecidable language. The language $L_2 = \varnothing$ is certainly finite, it's complement is $\overline{L_2} = \Sigma^*$, so that $\overline{L_1} \cap \overline{L_2} = \overline{L_1}$, and that one isn't decidable if $L_1$ isn't.

Comment: What about other finite $L_2$?